# Newline characters disappearing in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server-2008

I've seen 100's of posts online regarding how to remove CR/LFs from text in SQL Server.

My problem is that SQL Server appears to be *doing this itself* when I don't want it to...

Has anyone else come across this before?

Thanks

Comment: This is too vague; you need to elaborate.  How or where is it "doing it itself".  We can't read your mind.

Comment: I just ran into exactly what you describe. I place text into a parameter and after it goes into the varchar field in the database, the newline characters are stripped out.

Comment: Ended up solving the problem by converting the data field from varchar to nvarchar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reasons could be

1. You appear to have executed your script in "Results to Grid" mode, which is by default. Instead if you execute it in "Results to Text" mode, you could see the output clearly.
2. SQL Server will appear to have removed CR/LFs when you run the query in "Results to Grid" mode, which is not true.